# I did not secure a postdoc position this year. When should I start to apply again?

Tags: application, career-path, postdocs

I defended my PhD recently. I don't have a good CV to start with. In 5 years of my PhD, I managed to publish just 2 (first author) decent papers (I.F ~2.5 & 3.1). I applied for several postdoc positions this year, but did not get any positive response from the PIs.

Now, I am going to join my PhD advisor as a postdoc. She offered me a short-term postdoc position (~6 months) with a possibility of extending it to a year starting February next year.

I have couple of manuscripts ready to submit. I am hoping to submit them by mid-January.

**I would like some advice regarding when should I start applying for postdoc positions again?** 6 months will go by in a flash. I just want to secure a position where I can expand my knowledge and publish more papers.

I will start to apply for tenure track positions after 1.5 years. I am 30 years old now, so, I would be still eligible for positions with 35 years old limit for assistant professor position.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that there is an age limit for assistant professors? I think someone fooled you on that one.

Comment: @Buffy: A little Google searching turns up a rumor that such a limit exists in India, and also officials saying it isn't true: https://telanganatoday.com/fake-news-being-circulated-on-social-media-ugc

Comment: You should also keep in mind the possibility that you don't get a tenure track position and apply to some outside-of-academia positions. The worst that will do is give you an ego boost if you get a job offer at some company.

Comment: @puppetsockreinstateMonica yes, I am doing that too. I am open to all options.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I'd recommend that you start now. And also that you apply for tenure track positions in parallel. There is no reason to wait for either.

Make sure that when any position in your field gets opened, that you know about it. Don't focus your search too narrowly.

And so some things that give you visibility in addition to submitting papers. Attend conferences, as a presenter if possible, or as a workshop participant. But anything that introduces yourself to others in the field.

Comment: But my chance of getting a position is similar to what it was 6-7 months back. Only thing changed is that I have a degree now and the submitted paper got accepted. So, my profile is as bad as before. Should I still apply for the positions or send cold mails to professors? I was thinking of waiting till February end and start mailing again once I have got the manuscripts submitted. What do you advise?

Comment: Look for announcements. Cold emails are unlikely to give you much success. Apply for any positions that are reasonable. Cold emails from your advisor might be effective, but less likely if direct from you. And, your profile is improving. Keep it up.

Comment: One big thing has changed: a lot of other people already got postdocs and are no longer competing with you.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, failing to get a tenure track position by age 30 can seriously hamper your ability to succeed in my field. I don't know if we work in the same general area, but I would be seriously concerned with graduating so late with such a small number of publications.

Comment: In many countries/systems, it is more or less impossible to get a PhD by the age of 30.

Comment: @Mark How would that work? The typical progression for non-mature age students would be high school by 18, bachelors by 22, then either 5 years for a PhD or 2 years for a masters and 3 years for a PhD, right?

Comment: It’s actually quite common to take a year off after high school, and sometimes petiole can take 5 years instead of 4 years to finish undergraduate studies for many different reasons. From what i’ve seen, a masters typically takes 2 years, but you don’t get tome shaved off of your PhD because you have a masters already, so the PhD can take 4-5 years on top of the 2 done for masters. Accounting for that, you could be at the age of 30-32 by the time you finish a PhD.

Comment: @D.Gray  4 years undergraduate, 2 years masters puts you at 23, assuming you start college at 18. That gives you 7 years before you are 30. That much more than is actually needed. If you are still doing a PhD when you are 30, you either need to reassess your suitableness for the role you are preparing for, or get a different adviser.

Comment: @the_src_dude Sure, if you're on that path of a 4 year undergraduate and 2 year masters, but it's incredibly common for people to take longer, take breaks inbetween etc. The point being is that there is nothing inherently wrong about doing a PhD at an older age. If, however, you are dragging yourself through school, that's a different issue.

Comment: This certainly does *not* apply in my field, where time in industry is viewed very positively (and thank goodness for me, because I won't be finishing my PhD until 30 at least). Can you add more detail about what field you are in, and why your answer holds true?